# tomcat-use rorg.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload

Tags: web, tomcat7, web-deployment, myeclipse

I find something interesting, when I use myeclipse to deploy web project, I can upload picture successfully, but when I put .war  to tomcat/webapps and startup tomcat, I can't upload picture. And this is tomcat's log:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;)Ljava/util/List;
    at dao.ImageUploadDao.upload(ImageUploadDao.java:32)
    at servlet.imageUploadServlet.doPost(imageUploadServlet.java:42)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:277)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2407)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2396)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

So can somebody tell me why? I think myeclipse may do something in addition.
And I have the solution that to use org.apache.commons.fileupload.jar to instead of org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.jar,
the latter belongs to tomcat lib.

But I think the solution is to hide the fact,because when I don't export `org.apache.commons.fileupload.jar`, I use myeclipse to deploy project, is also ok, that illustrates `org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload.jar` is also ok.

Comment: Which release of MyEclipse are you using? Also, are you saying that ir you use the apache commons fileupload jar (instead of the tomcat fileupload jar) then you don't see a problem no matter how the app is deployed?

Comment: I use <br/> Version: 2014 <br/>
Build id: 12.0.0-20131202 <br/> I think becasue tomcat's lib don't have apache commons fileupload jar,so I don't see a problem. But that's why? <br/> When  I use org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload,the result of two deployments is different?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've fully understood the problem, but exporting to a war file should be the same as deploying directly to Tomcat,from MyEclipse 2014. But be aware that some dependencies (for example, org.apache.fileupload.jar) may have other dependencies, which may stop a class being loaded, if they aren't present. So ensure that all necessary dependencies, not already in Tomcat, are in the Deployment Assembly (this is accessible from the Project's Properties, under the MyEclipse section). Entries added to the deployment assembly are automatically added to the build path but it's the deployment assembly that determines what gets deployed.

MyEclipse 2014 will soon no longer be fully supported, so it might be worth thinking about upgrading to MyEclipse 2015 or 2016. There have been some bug fixes in the deployment area since 2014 but I can't say, yet, if your problem is a bug in 2014.

Comment: Maybe you are right,but does it have another reason,such as conflict between jars,because the probability of MyEclipse'bug is too much small?